# dynamic category level in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have 3 level deep categories in my laravel application like

```
Parent
 - Child One
  -- Child Two
```

When I use this nested categories in different parts such as menu, posts details etc. everything is just fine but recently I came cross an issue and I need guide to solve it.

## The issue

If any of my posts includes `child one` or `child two` level category it's a bit hard to provide correct route path for it, EXAMPLE:

```
Parent route :  site.com/p/slug
Child one route: site.com/parent_slug/childOne_slug
Child two route: site.com/parent_slug/childOne_slug/childTwo_slug
```

creating this much if statement in blade to make sure we get the right route for the right categories to me doesn't seem right. I was thinking about model function which returns final route depend on category parenting level in database but I wasn't sure if it's possible or not? and if it is, how?

## Question

1. Is it possible I pass category routes to the categories from model?
2. How to do that?

## Code

`Category model`

```
protected $fillable = [
        'title', 'slug', 'thumbnail', 'publish','mainpage', 'parent_id', 'color', 'template'
    ];

    public function posts(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Post::class, 'post_categories');
    }

    public function parent() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class, 'parent_id');
    }

    public function children() {
        return $this->hasMany(Category::class, 'parent_id');
    }
```

this is how currently i'm getting my posts categories:

```
@foreach($post->categories as $category)
  <a class="post-cat" href="#">{{$category->title}}</a>
@endforeach
```

Any idea?

## UPDATE

Well I solved it :-D here is the code I've made

```
public function getCatSlug(){

        if($this->parent_id != ''){ //child one

            if($this->parent->parent_id != ''){ //child two

                if($this->parent->parent->parent_id != ''){ //child three
                    return $this->parent->parent->parent->slug. '/'. $this->parent->parent->slug. '/'. $this->parent->slug. '/'. $this->slug;
                }

                return $this->parent->parent->slug. '/'. $this->parent->slug. '/'. $this->slug;
            }

            return $this->parent->slug. '/'. $this->slug;
        }

        return $this->slug;
    }
```

This does exactly what I needed it return slugs by orders like `parent/child1/child2`

## Issue

the issue here is now routing this dynamic path as the result of this function I can now have any deep level of path and this needs to be dynamic in routes as well.

### Route

my current route is like:

```
Route::get('/category/{slug}', 'Front\CategoryController@parent')->name('categoryparent');
```

which returns this path:

`site.com/category/parent`

but it doesn't return:

```
site.com/category/parent/child_one
site.com/category/parent/child_one/child_two
```

`Controller`

```
public function parent($slug){
  $category = Category::where('slug', $slug)->with('children')->first();
  $category->addView();
  $posts = $category->posts()->paginate(8);
  return view('front.categories.single', compact('category','posts'));
}
```

any idea?

## Update 2

based on `Matei Mihai` answer I've made custom classes in `App/Helpers` folder with details below:

`CategoryRouteService.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Helpers;

use App\Category;

class CategoryRouteService
{
    private $routes = [];

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->determineCategoriesRoutes();
    }

    public function getRoute(Category $category)
    {
        return $this->routes[$category->id];
    }

    private function determineCategoriesRoutes()
    {
        $categories = Category::all()->keyBy('id');

        foreach ($categories as $id => $category) {
            $slugs = $this->determineCategorySlugs($category, $categories);

            if (count($slugs) === 1) {
                $this->routes[$id] = url('p/' . $slugs[0]);
            }
            else {
                $this->routes[$id] = url('/' . implode('/', $slugs));
            }
        }
    }

    private function determineCategorySlugs(Category $category, Collection $categories, array $slugs = [])
    {
        array_unshift($slugs, $category->slug);

        if (!is_null($category->parent_id)) {
            $slugs = $this->determineCategorySlugs($categories[$category->parent_id], $categories, $slugs);
        }

        return $slugs;
    }
}
```

and `CategoryServiceProvider.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Helpers;

use App\Helpers\CategoryRouteService;

class CategoryServiceProvider
{
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->singleton(CategoryRouteService::class, function ($app) {
            // At this point the categories routes will be determined.
            // It happens only one time even if you call the service multiple times through the container.
            return new CategoryRouteService();
        });
    }
}
```

then I registered my provider to `composer.json` file like:

```
"autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        },
        "files": [
            "app/helpers/CategoryServiceProvider.php" //added here
        ]
    },
```

I also dumped autoloads and added this to my `Category` model

```
use App\Helpers\CategoryRouteService;
public function getRouteAttribute()
{
  $categoryRouteService = app(CategoryRouteService::class);
  return $categoryRouteService->getRoute($this);
}
```

then I used `{{$category->route}}` as my categries href attribute and I got this:

```
Argument 2 passed to App\Helpers\CategoryRouteService::determineCategorySlugs() must be an instance of App\Helpers\Collection, instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection given
```

which is refers to:

```
private function determineCategorySlugs(Category $category, Collection $categories, array $slugs = [])
    {
```

ideas?

Comment: A model method would be a good approach to this. The trick would be to recursively look up the parent category (and its parent category and so on) until you find that you've hit a top level category. You can then pass the slugs of each of those categories you've found into your route. Give it a shot and post your code if you need further help. It would be helpful to see your route definition in this case too, if you could post that - it would allow us to help you further.

Comment: @Jonathon updated.

Comment: @mafortis, I use your code.but my `$category->route` have the error. `Undefined offset: 0` . can help me?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but you must take care of the script performance because it could end up having a lot of DB queries done to determine each category route.

My recommendation would be to create a `CategoryRouteService` class which will be registered as singleton to keep the database queries as low as possible. It could be something like:

```
class CategoryRouteService
{
    private $routes = [];

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->determineCategoriesRoutes();
    }

    public function getRoute(Category $category)
    {
        return $this->routes[$category->id];
    }

    private function determineCategoriesRoutes()
    {
        $categories = Category::all()->keyBy('id');

        foreach ($categories as $id => $category) {
            $slugs = $this->determineCategorySlugs($category, $categories);

            if (count($slugs) === 1) {
                $this->routes[$id] = url('/p/' . $slugs[0]);
            }
            else {
                $this->routes[$id] = url('/' . implode('/', $slugs));
            }
        }
    }

    private function determineCategorySlugs(Category $category, Collection $categories, array $slugs = [])
    {
        array_unshift($slugs, $category->slug);

        if (!is_null($category->parent_id)) {
            $slugs = $this->determineCategorySlugs($categories[$category->parent_id], $categories, $slugs);
        }

        return $slugs;
    }
}
```

Now as I said before, you need a service provider to register this service. It should look like this:

```
class CategoryServiceProvider
{
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->singleton(CategoryRouteService::class, function ($app) {
            // At this point the categories routes will be determined.
            // It happens only one time even if you call the service multiple times through the container.
            return new CategoryRouteService();
        });
    }
}
```

This service provider must be added in the app configuration file.

The `Category` model could have a method which defines the `route` attribute:

```
class Category extends Model
{
    public function getRouteAttribute()
    {
        $categoryRouteService = app(CategoryRouteService::class);

        return $categoryRouteService->getRoute($this);
    }

    /** Your relationships methods **/
}
```

Finally, you can use it in your blade views simply by using `$category->route`.

```
@foreach($post->categories as $category)
  <a class="post-cat" href="{{$category->route}}">{{$category->title}}</a>
@endforeach
```

Please note that there could be other solutions better than this. I just came across this one without thinking too much. Also, the code above was not tested so please be aware that it might need some minor changes to make it work properly.

Comment: hi, thank you for your answer, while you posting this answer I was updating my question. Would you mind check my update and see if your answer is valid or needs some changes before i test it? thanks

Comment: I saw your updated question. The problem there is exactly the first thing I wrote in the answer. If you would have 100 categories you will end up having at least 3-400 db queries only to determine the categories routes. With my solution there will be only 1 query

Comment: Sound perfect, but i have no experience making services is there any command for it or how? Where should i make it?

Comment: you can create a new directory anywhere in your app and create those classes inside it. Also, you must add them the proper namespace. like `App\MyCategoriesDirectory`

Comment: I've made folder named `Helpers` in `App` folder and this is the content can you please verify that I did good or not? http://collabedit.com/canrk

Comment: i am getting this error `Argument 2 passed to App\Helpers\CategoryRouteService::determineCategorySlugs() must be an instance of App\Helpers\Collection, instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection given, called in C:\laragon\www\rudyblog\app\Helpers\CategoryRouteService.php on line 26 (View: C:\laragon\www\rudyblog\resources\views\front\posts\single.blade.php)`

Comment: Updated based on your code please kindly check it, thanks.

Comment: you are missing `use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection`. Otherwise it looks good

Comment: Also please make sure that you added the service provider otherwise it will query the database multiple times instead of once

Comment: just a small thing.. instead of adding the provider in the composer json, you should add it to `config/app.php` inside the providers key add a new entry: `App\Helpers\CategoryServiceProvider`. That's all!

Comment: hi, thanks for advice my page is loading now and i can get true paths but now i have view issue, if you see `public function parent($slug){` i was getting `single.blade.php` as view of my category with prefix of `category/` in my routes then you used `p/` in `class CategoryRouteService` which is fine but the problem is now every category link i click first of all `doesn't have Category OR p` as prefix. Second `I get 404 error for any category deep i open`. any idea?

Comment: Oh and may I know why you used `id` while i am getting categories by `slug`? e.g. `return $this->routes[$category->id];` - `$categories = Category::all()->keyBy('id');` - `if (count($slugs) === 1) {` - `$this->routes[$id] = url('category/' . $slugs[0]);` etc.