# laravel getting dynamic view based on url

Tags: php, laravel

I have made dynamic category routes by adding custom class to my app ([how i did it is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53098060/dynamic-category-level-in-laravel)) now i need to make my blade works with this dynamic path.

## Logic

based on categories deeps my url will create such as:

```
site.com/category/parent
site.com/category/parent/child
site.com/category/parent/child/child
etc.
```

so far my view is just loading for `site.com/category/parent` for other urls it return `404` error.

## code

`CategoryRouteService`

```
class CategoryRouteService
{
    private $routes = [];

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->determineCategoriesRoutes();
    }

    public function getRoute(Category $category)
    {
        return $this->routes[$category->id];
    }

    private function determineCategoriesRoutes()
    {
        $categories = Category::all()->keyBy('id');

        foreach ($categories as $id => $category) {
            $slugs = $this->determineCategorySlugs($category, $categories);

            if (count($slugs) === 1) {
                $this->routes[$id] = url('category/' . $slugs[0]);
            }
            else {
                $this->routes[$id] = url('category/' . implode('/', $slugs));
            }
        }
    }

    private function determineCategorySlugs(Category $category, Collection $categories, array $slugs = [])
    {
        array_unshift($slugs, $category->slug);

        if (!is_null($category->parent_id)) {
            $slugs = $this->determineCategorySlugs($categories[$category->parent_id], $categories, $slugs);
        }

        return $slugs;
    }
}
```

`CategoryServiceProvider`

```
class CategoryServiceProvider
{
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->singleton(CategoryRouteService::class, function ($app) {
            // At this point the categories routes will be determined.
            // It happens only one time even if you call the service multiple times through the container.
            return new CategoryRouteService();
        });
    }
}
```

`model`

```
//get dynamic slug routes
    public function getRouteAttribute()
    {
        $categoryRouteService = app(CategoryRouteService::class);

        return $categoryRouteService->getRoute($this);
    }
```

`blade`

```
//{{$categoryt->route}} returning routes
<a class="post-cat" href="{{$category->route}}">{{$category->title}}</a>
```

`route`

```
//show parent categories with posts
Route::get('/category/{slug}', 'Front\CategoryController@parent')->name('categoryparent');
```

`controller`

```
public function parent($slug){
        $category = Category::where('slug', $slug)->with('children')->first();
        $category->addView();
        $posts = $category->posts()->where('publish', '=', 1)->paginate(8);
        return view('front.categories.single', compact('category','posts'));
}
```

**Note:** I'm not sure about this but i think i my route is kinda static! I mean it just getting 1 slug with it while my category can goes 2, 3 or 4 slug deep and it doesn't make sense to me to make several route and keep repeating `Route::get('/category/{slug}/{slug}/{slug}` like that.

As I said I'm not sure about this, please share your idea and solutions if you may.

## UPDATE

based on `Leena Patel` answer I changed my route but when I get more than 1 slug in my url it returns error:

`Example`

```
route: site.com/category/resources (works)

route: site.com/category/resources/books/ (ERROR)
route: site.com/category/resources/books/mahayana/sutra (ERROR)
```

`error`

```
Call to a member function addView() on null
```

on

```
$category->addView();
```

when I comment that it returns error for `$posts` part. then error for my blade where i returned category title `{{$category->title}}`

So basically it seem doesn't recognize this function for returning view of category routes.

`here is my function`

```
public function parent($slug){
        $category = Category::where('slug', $slug)->with('children')->first();
        $category->addView();
        $posts = $category->posts()->where('publish', '=', 1)->paginate(8);
        return view('front.categories.single', compact('category','posts'));
}
```

any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You can try using Route Pattern like below

```
Route::get('/category/{slug}', 'Front\CategoryController@parent')->where('slug','.+')->name('categoryparent')
```

So if you have more than one slugs in your url like `/category/slug1/slug2`

Your `addView()` method will work for `one record` and not for `Collection` So add `foreach` loop to achieve this.

```
public function parent($slug){
    // $slug  will be `slug1/slug2`
    $searchString = '/';
    $posts = array();

    if( strpos($slug, $searchString) !== false ) {
        $slug_array = explode('/',$slug);
    }

    if(isset($slug_array))
    {
         foreach($slug_array as $slug)
         {
             $category = Category::where('slug', $slug)->with('children')->first();
             $category->addView();
             $posts_array = $category->posts()->where('publish', '=', 1)->paginate(8);
             array_push($posts,$posts_array);
         }
    }
    else
    {
          $category = Category::where('slug', $slug)->with('children')->first();
          $category->addView();
          $posts = $category->posts()->where('publish', '=', 1)->paginate(8);
    }

    return view('front.categories.single', compact('category','posts'));
}
```

Hope it helps!

Documentation : https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing#route-parameters

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183004/discussion-on-answer-by-leena-patel-laravel-getting-dynamic-view-based-on-url).

Answer (score 0):

Create route

```
Route::get('category/{cat}', 'YourController@mymethod');
```

Add this to your Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php 's boot method

```
public function boot()
{
    Route::pattern('cat', '.+'); //add this

    parent::boot();
}
```

In your method:

```
public function mymethod($cat){
    echo $cat;  //access your route
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use optional URL sections in the route and use conditionals in controllers. Try this:

In your **route**:

```
Route::get('/category/{parent?}/{child1?}/{child2?}', 'Front\CategoryController@parent')->name('categoryparent');
```

In your **controller**:

```
public function mymethod($category, $parent, $child1, $child2){
    if(isset($child2)){
        //use $category, $parent, $child1, $child2 and return view
    } else if(isset($child1)){
        //use $category, $parent, $child1 and return view
    } else if(isset($parent)){
        //use $category, $parent and return view
    } else {
        //return view for $category
    }

}
```

Comment: so if i do this `/category/{parent?}/{child1?}/{child2?}` and my url only contain `parent` part will be issue then?

Comment: `/category/{parent?}/{child1?}/{child2?}` means `category` is always required. So if your url contains `parent`, you must provide `category`, and that will be fine.